# Automate the spark submit job with DB2 connection

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark, db2

I have a spark job that I call with my shell scripts using the spark submit command line tool.
I need to pass the credentials for DB2 connection username and password to the jar file. 
The requirement is that the username and password be not readable.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using hadoop credential API

Hadoop has introduced keystore since version hadoop 2.6. You can pass the key store path and alias to your spark program and get the password from the keystore at run time

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#credential

Here is sample Java program 
https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/refs/heads/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/alias/JavaKeyStoreProvider.java